# Having problems updating after esx host problem

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

So I have a VM that had to be hard shutdown.  I can't get the error to stop.

CentOS 7.x latest

```
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$ sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.mirrors.wvstateu.edu
* epel: mirror.cs.princeton.edu
* extras: mirror.riverfrontnetworks.com
* updates: mirror.stjschools.org
Cleaning up unfinished transaction journals
Cleaning up 2016-05-18.11:05.17
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.mirrors.wvstateu.edu
* epel: mirror.cs.princeton.edu
* extras: mirror.riverfrontnetworks.com
* updates: mirror.stjschools.org
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-106.el7_2.4 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4 for package: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.17-106.el7_2.6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (@updates)
        Requires: glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
        Removing: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 (@updates)
            glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.4
        Updated By: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 (updates)
            glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.6
        Available: glibc-common-2.17-105.el7.x86_64 (base)
            glibc-common = 2.17-105.el7
        Available: glibc-common-2.17-106.el7_2.1.x86_64 (updates)
            glibc-common = 2.17-106.el7_2.1
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64
glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-common = ('0', '2.17', '106.el7_2.6')
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$ sudo yum check
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror



glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64
glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.6.x86_64 has missing requires of glibc-common = ('0', '2.17', '106.el7_2.6')
Error: check all
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$ ping 10.150.1.63
PING 10.150.1.63 (10.150.1.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.150.1.63: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.695 ms
64 bytes from 10.150.1.63: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.416 ms
^C
--- 10.150.1.63 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.416/0.555/0.695/0.141 ms
[user@asm-dmz01 ~]$
```

Comment: That is interesting, it doesn't think you have `glibc-common` installed. Have you tried manually installing that one package at the same version as your installed version of `glibc` ?

Comment: no trying this out [link](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2576)[/link]

Answer (score 0):

The last lines explain the issue. You shut down a VM that was in the middle of appending/changing the rpmdb. You will have to rebuid the rpmdb to fix the issue. If for some reason you do NOT have a backup of /var/lib/rpm, you will have to do it manually. Plenty of manuals, explanations and posts describing how.